# How to make a negative Fibonacci sequence in Java using recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, fibonacci, negative-number

I have to write a program that returns Fibonacci number, but not only positive. I don't know what is not right in the way I've wrote it, but my code works with positive numbers and not with negative ones.

```
public static int negFib(int n) {
    if(n==0 || n==1) {
        return n;
    }
    if(n==-1) {
        return 1;
    }
    if(n<0 && n%2==0) {
        //return negFib(n+2) - negFib(n+1);
        return (-1<<(n+1))*(negFib(n-1) + negFib(n-2); // Fibonacci negative
        //F(n)=F(n+2)−F(n+1)
        //F(−1)=F(1)−F(0)=1−0=1 , F(−2)=F(0)−F(1)=0−1=−1
    } 
    return negFib(n-1) + negFib(n-2); //Fibonacci positive      
}
```

Comment: You're not using `a`. You create it as `abs(n)` and then don't do anything with it. Your calculation with negative `n` calculates `negFib(n-1)` and `negFib(n-2)`, which are both *further away* from your base case, so your recursion will be too huge to calculate.

Comment: why not just `if (n < 0) return negFib(n+2)-negFib(n+1)`  - exactly as the given formula...

Comment: and no need to check for `-1` neither for `n%2==0` in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you want to use the F<sub>−n</sub> = (−1)<sup>n+1</sup>F<sub>n</sub> formula:

```
public static int negFib(int n) {
    if(n==0 || n==1) {
        return n;
    }
    if(n==-1) {
        return 1;
    }
    if(n<0) {
        int sign = n % 2 == 0 ? -1 : 1;
        return sign * negFib(-n);
    } else {
        return negFib(n-1) + negFib(n-2);
    }     
}
```

Your attempt had several issues:

- for negative `n` (either odd or even), you should make the recursive call for `-n-1` and `-n-2`.
- your calculation of the sign - `(-1<<(n+1))` - is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
long f[] = new long[(int) (n+2)];  
long i;

f[0]=0;
f[1]=1;

for (i=2; i <= n; i++) { 
   f[(int) i] = f[(int) (i-1)] + f[(int) (i-2)];
}
```

Comment: Why all the casting? Looks really suspicious.